# Unresolved Symbol in Eclipse CDT because of a conflict of name in another struct

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I tried different settings of indexer but couldn't resolve this. In a header file I have an struct like this:

```
typedef struct {
 ...
int counter[2];
} foo_t;
```

Now in another function I am using

```
void foo_func(...)
{
int counter = 1;
...
int a = counter * 2;  //This will give unresolved symbol for counter
```

In all the code the `counter` is marked as an unresolved symbol and if I hit F3 on it it goes to the definition inside that foo_t struct. How can I change the settings in the indexer to avoid this?

Thanks